# Wordpress REST API 404 error when requesting Custom Post Type with Mobile Browser

Tags: json, wordpress, ionic-framework, wp-api, wordpress-rest-api

I am confused. I am using Wordpress REST Api to build a mobile app with Ionic. I am trying to implement regular post type and one of my custom post type.

I can make a get request for the standard post type "http://www.example.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts" and it works.

I did the same with my custom post type "http://www.example.org/wp-json/wp/v2/shows" and when I test it in my browser it works BUT when I use chrome and the mobile simulator it gives me an  404 error : rest_no_route

Any ideas why this error occurs, especially only for custom post types?

Comment: Did you set 'show_in_rest' to true when setting up your custom post type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default custom post type won't be available. You need to add the below snippets to `functions.php` of your theme file:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_rest_support', 25 );
function custom_post_type_rest_support() {
  global $wp_post_types;

  $post_type_name = 'show';
  if( isset( $wp_post_types[ $post_type_name ] ) ) {
    $wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->show_in_rest = true;
    $wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->rest_base =  $post_type_name ;
    $wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->rest_controller_class = 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller';
  }
}
```